# Unable to connect Docker Windows Container using VNC server

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, containers, windows-container

### I have a problem connecting a windows container I wish to use for running automation scripts.

---

> Host - Primary Operating System which is running HyperV and docker
>   (Access to UI)
>
> Target - container hosted on Host using docker (No access to UI)

**Following are the details of the environment am working on:**

1. Container image : mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore
2. Installed components include: Maven / Java / VNCServer.
3. Docker container is running on docker using HyperV on the same machine I wish to connect this container to.
4. Host Operating System is windows 10 pro.
5. I installed all softwares in the Target by copying them first and performing a silent installation.

**I tried the following solutions but none have been possibly working out.**

6. Started container with command : docker run -itd -p 5920:5920 --name containername imagename
7. Started container with command : docker start containername
8. Got access to cmd of Target node : docker exec -it containername cmd
9. Ran tasklist to ensure : vnserver was running
10. On Host supplied the IP address of the Target along with port numbers 5920 which results in errors stating timed out connection.

> I need to be able to see the UI of the Target system and be able to
>   control it on the host.
>   Tried Commands from Teamviewer -id -p but it itself launches the UI which is not available on the Target system.

*Is there a way I can get this working?*

Please let me know if you need any additional information.